# How can I prevent the Microsoft Outlook web interface from automatically placing emails in the junk folder?

Tags: spam-prevention, outlook-on-the-web

I couldn't find any option when searching for "junk" in the Outlook settings:

[image: One irrelevant result: "Junk email reporting: Report junk email to help improve the accuracy of the junk email filter."]

How can I prevent the Microsoft Outlook web interface from automatically placing emails in the junk folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to options > Mail > Accounts > Block or allow > Don't move email to my Junk Email folder:

[image]

I don't know what this configuration page doesn't show up when searching for "junk" in the Outlook settings.